# Show Rails debugging errors (detailed_exceptions) if the request user is an admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

Especially for smaller projects, it's nice to get more feedback in production than:

[image: Rails Production Generic Error Message: We're sorry, something went wrong]

I saw there's a variable called `Rails.configuration.consider_all_requests_local`.
I'm wondering if this could be used to allow `admin` level users to see the full debugging in production, when the production.rb configuration usually sets:

```
  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
```

I've tried several variations of functions setting `consider_all_requests_local = true` inside of the application controller, but it's not impacting errors actually being displayed or not.

Comment: Is the usefulness of this really worth the potential security holes that you're creating? There is a reason why Rails isn't configured to use these settings in production. If you find it annoying to ssh in to check the logs use a logging service like Scout, Loggly, etc.

Comment: @max You could make the exact same argument about any rails site that has a /admin section built into the main site rather than managing admin tools via a completely separate network requiring another layer of security. There is a time and a place for everything. Wisdom is in knowing the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-consider-all-requests-local there's a function called `show_detailed_exceptions?` that's designed to be overridden in controllers to specify which requests should provide debugging information on errors.

So in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` I just added the `show_details_exceptions?` function:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def show_detailed_exceptions?
    request.session[:user_id].present? && User.find(request.session[:user_id]).is_admin?
  end

end
```

## Two firefox windows side by side

#### Rails running on `localhost`, but `RAILS_ENV=production`.

| Left Window | Right Window |
| --- | --- |
| Normal, non admin user | logged in as `admin` user |
| Typical production style exception | Development style exception |
| **"something went wrong"** | Much faster to troubleshoot |
| Default "firefox container" | separate [firefox container](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) |

[image: Rails generic error vs Detailed Exception, depending on logged in user]